# Hacer algo necesitase o no

Tags: traducción, gramática, modismos

> La norma no escrita en las relaciones con las minorías parlamentarias de CiU ha permitido tradicionalmente durante los últimos veinte años que la Generalitat distribuyera estratégicamente a sus agentes delegados en las comisiones de control económico. **El pacto se ha hecho efectivo siempre y con independencia de que el Gobierno surgido de las urnas necesitase o no los votos del grupo catalán para imponer una mayoría estable** en el Congreso de los Diputados.

I was reading this paragraph in El Confidencial online, and what I don't know is what the second sentence means (with this "surgir .. necesitase o no" syntax). Could you help me?

Comment: The sentence is a bit complicated, it can be simplified as _El pacto siempre se ha hecho efectivo, independientemente de si el Gobierno surgido de las urnas necesitaba los votos de CiU ..._.

Answer (score 8):

The phrase:

> ... surgido de las urnas ...

means that that government was **elected**, but focusing in the fact that it was elected by vote (hence the word **urnas**).

So, that phrase is just a complement of the noun **government**. Bearing that in mind, you can just see:

> ... de que el Gobierno (el que surgió de las urnas) necesitase o no los votos ...

That can be reduced even further:

> ... de que el Gobierno necesitase o no los votos ...

Then, the phrase: **necesitase o no**, means "whether it needs that or not", that is to say, in both cases.

Comment: It might be worth to note that _necesitase_ is Past Imperfect of Subjunctive tense of [the verb _necesitar_](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/EsVerbs.aspx?v=necesitar), and the phrase _"dependiendo de que [alguien] necesitase..."_ is a nice example of the use of subjunctive which is a thorny subject for Spanish language learners.